# Regenerate a designer.cs file

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio

[image]

I somehow managed to mess up the structure of the Form `UserLogin`. The Form listed above. `SQLServerSettings` has the correct structure. The `UserLogin.Designer.cs` file isn't linked to the Form somehow. What should I do?